# Toggle class/background on current selection (jquery)

Tags: jquery, removeclass, toggleclass

How i can change background in span (class: right-icon-opened) here?

I try use toggleClass and add/removeClass, but i dont know how do it on current element

Have any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/inc1uder/pK3Vn/2/

P.S. sorry for my bad english(

Comment: Does "current selection" mean the node the mouse is over?

Comment: when menu opened change arrow in right to arrow on down

Comment: You should apologize for all the inline scripts not for your English ;)

Comment: provide context for DOM traversal in your JS code e.g. `$('#sro').slideToggle(300); $('.right-icon', $('#sro')).removeClass('right-icon').addClass('right-icon-opened'); return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this too.

http://jsfiddle.net/pK3Vn/5/

Answer (score 0):

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/4FSMV/6/
And in future please consider putting all the scripts in `<script>` tag or in .js file